# sonataadminbundle sandbox datafixture load error

Tags: symfony, pdo, fixtures, sonata-admin

I have installed SonataAdminBundle sandbox for symfony and when i try to load the fixtures in the DB it throws an PDOexcetion which says

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 column 'name' cannot be null".
```

I tried to figure out the problem and I found some functions which seems that have not been defined!

LoadMediaData.php

```
class LoadMediaData extends AbstractFixture implements ContainerAwareInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    ...
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        ...
        $gallery->setName($faker->sentence(4));
        $gallery->setDefaultFormat('small');
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

functions like 'sentence' have a warning that says "method 'sentence' not found in class \Faker\Generator...'

i have followed the instruction and haven't modified the code, but i don't know why this is happening:( (googled and nothing useful came out)